# long number is not updating properly in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I tried to update a field in a document which was long integer. But it was updated to the value '14818435007969200' instead of '14818435007969199'.

```
db.getCollection('title').updateMany({},
{$set:{'skillId':[NumberLong(14818435007969199)]}})

db.getCollection('title').find({})

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5853351c0274072315da2426"),
    "skillId" : [ 
        NumberLong(14818435007969200)
    ]
}
```

Is there any solution? I am using robomongo 0.9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mongo shell treats all numbers as floating point values. So while using the ***[NumberLong()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/shell-types/)*** wrapper pass the long value as string or risk the loss for precision or conversion mismatches.

This should work as expected.

```
db.getCollection('title').updateMany({},
{$set:{'skillId':[NumberLong("14818435007969199")]}})
```

Just to demonstrate for example.

So when converting `14818435007969199` to binary base 2 value  you get `110100101001010100100111000010110001101111011110110000` which when converted back to base 10 is `14818435007969200`

You can checkout the ***[floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)*** for more details.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example with where condition in the query

```
 db.CustomerRatibs.update(
    { custRatibId:'8b19bfdbac7b468b9c3edafc37ad5409' },
    { $set:
       {
        uAt : NumberLong(1536581726000)
       }
    },
    {
        multi:false
    }
 )
```